# Why does File.ReadAllLinesAsync block UI thread in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I'm using .Net core 3.1 and the method File.ReadAllLinesAsync blocks UI thread in wpf when awaiting it, so I took a look at the source code of this method ([here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/0f7f38c4fd323b26da10cce95f857f77f0f09b48/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs#L909)) and saw that it uses async methods of StreamReader class. So I'm wondering if it is normal and if it is why ?
Thanks in advance, here is my code:

```
private async void LoadFileButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog()
            {
                Multiselect = false,
                DefaultExt = "txt",
                Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
            };
            var b = fileDialog.ShowDialog();
            if (!b.HasValue || !b.Value)
                return;
            var l = await File.ReadAllLinesAsync(fileDialog.FileName, Encoding.UTF8);

        }
```

edit:
Well I just tried the following code :

```
using (var reader = File.OpenText(fileDialog.FileName))
            {
                l = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                
            }
```

and it worked without blocking UI thread. So I'm starting to think if maybe the File.ReadAllLinesAsync method is broken.

Comment: Try using `await File.ReadAllLinesAsync(fileDialog.FileName, Encoding.UTF8).ConfigureAwait(false)`

Comment: @AlexBakanov thanks but same issue is happening.

Comment: How about `var l = await Task.Run(() => File.ReadAllLines(fileDialog.FileName, Encoding.UTF8));`? Does that also block?

Comment: @Clemens this indeed work but I'm trying to understand why the File.ReadAllLinesAsync blocks UI thread whereas from what I see in the source code of this method it shouldn't.

Comment: You're awaiting ReadAllLinesAsync method, so main thread will wait for the result of ReadAllLinesAsync which freeze the UI.
Solution is using a background thread/task or using a BackgroundWorker. My recommendation is using a thread/task as you've more control and also it's professional.